# Cannot install composer laravel/socialite

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-socialite

I am having error in installing `laravel/socialite` in my laravel 5.2 project.

I tried this -- `composer laravel/socialite` but gets an error like this.

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write this

```
composer require laravel/socialite
```

this is the command. Use this

Answer (score 0):

To install a package to laravel using composer you need to add `require` method after `composer`

Try doing like this

```
composer require laravel/socialite
```